# Minimum number of operations to make all of the strings (objects) the same

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

> Let $A$ be an alphabet, $K$ and $N$ be natural numbers and $X$ be a
>   list of $N$ strings over $A$, each one consisting of $K$ letters. You
>   have one operation ($@f$): convert a string from $X$ to
>   another string from $X$. The cost of applying $@f$ over $(X_1, X_2)$ is
>   the number of letters that one needs to change so that $X_1$ becomes
>   $X_2$. (thank you @mvw for pointing out that this is called "Hamming distance")
>
> You want to know (in a polynomial time) the minimum cost of making all
>   of the strings the same.

My solution: Create a matrix (a graph) $N \times N$ showing the cost of every possible operation over $X$ and then find the minimum spanning tree (let's call it $@T$). Using $@T$ I can run a BFS like algorithm starting from the leafs down to the "center" and calculate the total cost of the operations.

My question: Is my solution correct (I can not prove it - it only feels correct) and if not - can you give me a correct one?

Thank you for your time

Comment: It might be a clearer approach to think of this as a shortest path problem, for which there are well-known algorithms (such as Dijkstra's, which assumes the cost of each change is positive).

Comment: "You have one operation"; but presumably of all possible operations $@f:X\to X$ you can choose one you like best? Otherwise there is no guarantee that any number of applications of $@f$ will make all strings the same. Next, what _is_ the "cost of making all of the strings the same"? If $K=1$, $N=3$, and you have strings $a$, $b$, $c$ with $@f(a)=b$ and $@f(b)=c$, is the cost $2$ (cost $1$ from $\{a,b,c\}$ to $\{b,c\}$, and another $1$ to reach $\{c\}$) or is it $3$ (apply $@f$ twice to change $a$ to $c$, and once more to change $b$ to $c$)?

Comment: @hardmath - shortest part from where to where?

Comment: @David K - 1. you have a list, not a set : ) 2. The problem always has a solution - take the first string and make it like the second, then make them both like the 3rd one and so on...

Comment: @David K - I also can not understand the part of you comment where you talk about choosing f. f is well defined - it accepts two strings: X1 and X2 and makes X1 like X2 using some resources (the cost of the operation)... hmmm maybe my syntax is bad - I'm referring to "f: X -> X", maybe it should be: "f: X x X -> N"?

Comment: $K=1, N=3$, you have strings $a$, $b$, and $c$; $@f(a)=b,$ $@f(b)=a$, $@f(c)=c$. No solution. So for the question to make sense, either we assume you are given an $@f$ for which a solution exists, and you must find a minimal solution with that $@f$, or you are allowed to construct $@f$ to find a minimal-cost solution over all  possible $@f$. It's unclear to me which of those interpretations is intended.

Comment: As to the "list" vs. "set" question: in my (solvable) $a,b,c$ example, is the total cost $2$ or is it $3$? If you say $2$, then I say you're treating the strings as a set despite calling them a list. If you really mean "list," then that example requires _two_ applications of $@f(b)=c$, one for the string that was originally $a$ and one for the string that was originally $b$.

Comment: I've posted an Answer to clarify how the problem can generally be considered as a shortest path problem and what graph is involved (although I'd assumed that was pretty clear).  However my Answer serves mainly to point out a flaw in the current formulation of the problem, and I look forward to seeing the Question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the initial list $X = (x_1, \ldots x_n)$ with $x_i \in A^k$.

> operation (@f): convert a string from X to another string from X.

This means $@f(X_i, j) = X_j$ and the final list $X_f$ will look like this
$$
X_f = (x_f, \ldots, x_f)\quad (f \in \{1,..,n\})
$$

So, assuming $(A1)$ that it is sufficient for reaching the minimum to touch each string once, converting it to the final string (which might be a wrong assumption), the problem is finding
$$
c = \min_i c_i = \sum_{j = 1}^n \Delta(x_i, x_j)
$$
where $c_i$ is the cost to change all words from $X$ into $x_i$ and 
$\Delta(x,y)$ is the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).
We define
$$
H_{ij} = \Delta(x_i, x_j)
$$
and note that this matrix has $H_{ii} = 0$ ($\Delta$ is semi-definite) and $H_{ij} = H_{ji}$ ($\Delta$ is symmetric).

To calculate $c$ we need to find the minimal row sum (or column sum) of $H$.

We need to calculate $n(n-1)/2 = (n^2 - n)/2$ Hamming distances and apply $n(n-2)$ additions.

Each Hamming distance calculation of two strings of the length $k$ needs $k$ symbol comparisons and up to $k$ increments.

This gives $O(k n^2)$ symbol comparisons, $O(n^2)$ integer additions and $(n-1)$ integer comparisons.

Here the assumption $(A2)$ is that each $H_{ij}$ $(i<j)$ must be calculated independently, which might be too pessimistic.

**Example:**

For this list $X$

```
 1. 'A.........'
 2. 'ALL.......'
 3. 'COST......'
 4. 'IN........'
 5. 'KNOW......'
 6. 'MAKING....'
 7. 'MINIMUM...'
 8. 'OF........'
 9. 'POLYNOMIAL'
10. 'SAME......'
11. 'STRINGS...'
12. 'THE.......'
13. 'TIME......'
14. 'TO........'
15. 'WANT......'
16. 'YOU.......'
```

we get

```
 1: [ 0  2  4  2  4  6  7  2 10  4  7  3  4  2  4  3 ], c =  64
 2: [ 2  0  4  3  4  6  7  3  9  4  7  3  4  3  4  3 ], c =  66
 3: [ 4  4  0  4  4  6  7  4  9  4  7  4  4  3  3  3 ], c =  70
 4: [ 2  3  4  0  3  6  7  2 10  4  7  3  4  2  4  3 ], c =  64
 5: [ 4  4  4  3  0  6  7  4 10  4  7  4  4  4  4  4 ], c =  73
 6: [ 6  6  6  6  6  0  5  6  9  5  4  6  6  6  5  6 ], c =  88
 7: [ 7  7  7  7  7  5  0  7  9  7  6  7  6  7  6  7 ], c = 102
 8: [ 2  3  4  2  4  6  7  0 10  4  7  3  4  2  4  3 ], c =  65
 9: [10  9  9 10 10  9  9 10  0 10  9 10 10  9 10  9 ], c = 143
10: [ 4  4  4  4  4  5  7  4 10  0  6  4  2  4  3  4 ], c =  69
11: [ 7  7  7  7  7  4  6  7  9  6  0  7  7  7  7  7 ], c = 102
12: [ 3  3  4  3  4  6  7  3 10  4  7  0  3  2  4  3 ], c =  66
13: [ 4  4  4  4  4  6  6  4 10  2  7  3  0  3  4  4 ], c =  69
14: [ 2  3  3  2  4  6  7  2  9  4  7  2  3  0  4  2 ], c =  60
15: [ 4  4  3  4  4  5  6  4 10  3  7  4  4  4  0  4 ], c =  70
16: [ 3  3  3  3  4  6  7  3  9  4  7  3  4  2  4  0 ], c =  65
c_min = 60, i_min = 14
final word: 'TO........'
```

Source code [here](https://gist.github.com/4cbfec4c422da61a08e8).

Answer (score 1):

The Question formulation seems to present a "list" $X$ of $N$ strings, all of equal length $K$, and a cost function (not identified by specific notation) that applies when applying "@f" to a member of the list to get another member of that list.

The shortest path formulation I have in mind is a directed graph whose nodes are the $N$ members of the list $X$, and whose edges are the connections from one such node to another by applying @f to $X$. The length of an edge is the cost associated with that function application.

Note that as formulated there is no choice involved in the application of function @f, so that one has only one option to try and convert string $x_1 \in X$ to string $x_2 \in X$.  One applies the function @f repeatedly, starting with $x_1$ and hoping to end up with $x_2$ eventually.

Perhaps the Question stands in need of editing, but this is a procedure that is of linear complexity in $N$, since one can stop as soon as the prescribed sequence repeats, unless one is able to reach $x_2$ before such a repetition.

In one of the OP's Comments it is suggested that the notation should be changed so that $f:X\times X \to \mathbb{N}$ gives the cost of converting one string to another, i.e. $f(x_1,x_2) = m$ is number $m$ of different letters (in the same positions?) between strings $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Since this notation envisions being able to convert any string to any other string for just the cost of the number of letter differences, one would have a complete graph on $X$, an edge between every pair of strings.

It is still a little vague what is meant by "the minimum cost of making all of the strings the same".  Should we total all the cost pairs $f(x_1,x_2)$ over $X\times X$?  Should we try to "amortize" the cost of converting $x_1$ to $x_2$ by reusing that conversion when making $x_1$ into $x_3$ (adding merely a cost for making $x_2$ into $x_3$)?

I look forward to seeing these clarifications incorporated into the Question.

Comment: The ambiguities mentioned here are the same ones I was concerned about. Thanks for writing it up like this.